# Getting a string from PHP using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Basically, I have a jQuery script which detects when a certain button is pressed. When the button is pressed, the script is meant to make a GET request to a separate PHP file. The PHP file should return a string to the JavaScript file, but I have multiple errors in both my scripts, creating a problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#generate').click(function(){
       $.get("give.php?data").done(function(info){
        console.log(info);
       });
      });
    });
</script>
```

When logging *info*, I get nothing. Literally, nothing.

```
<?php
   $f_contents = file("combo.txt");
   $line = $f_contents[array_rand($f_contents)];
   $data = $line;
   $_GET['data']
?>
```

That's my PHP script.

If someone can help me out, I would appreciate it. None of the posts on the internet helped me out.

Thanks!

*Oh and yes, I know my code is terrible.*

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mElo1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No, you're code is not terrible
- You need to know the difference between `$_GET['data']` and echoing out variable called `$data` .. If you know its Ok

To solve your problem you need to

- Directly access the php file in the browser something like `http://localhost/give.php` and play with the php file to get the result printed out .. *you may need to check the `combo.txt` file directory it may `./combo.txt` or something else*
- Then copy the fullurl like `http://localhost/give.php` then paste it to `$.get(fullurl....`

Some notes

- You've to echo out the data in your php file `echo $_GET['data']` or `echo $data` to echo the file content data
- With `$.get` you can use `$.get('url' , {} , function(response){ console.log(response); });`